# Creating List of Equations

Tags: table-of-contents, equations

I want to create list of equations, I used:

```
\documentclass[final]{york-thesis}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}

\makefrontmatter

\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}

\listofmyequations

\input{Chapter1}
\input{Chapter2}
\input{Chapter3}
\input{Chapter4}

\end{document}
```

It created the list of equations, but I have three issues:

1. The Table of Content, List of Tables, List of Figures (which are automatically generated by the latex template file) is not starting at the beginning of the page as they were before this command.
2. List of Tables, List of Figures were included in the Table of Content before but now they disappear.
3. I would like to add also List of Equations to the Table of Content.

Below is part of cls file where I guess is related of the construction of the Table of Content, I hope it helps figuring out why the Table of Content, List of Tables and List of Figures are not starting at the beginning of pages.

```
\newboolean{hasfigures}\setboolean{hasfigures}{false}
\newboolean{hastables}\setboolean{hastables}{false}
\newboolean{masters}\setboolean{masters}{false}
\newcommand{\spacing}[1]{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{#1}%
\large\normalsize}


\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{List of Figures}
\renewcommand\listtablename{List of Tables}
\renewcommand\bibname{Bibliography}
\newcommand{\contentsheader}[2] { \addtocontents{#1} {
  \centerline{\underline{#2}\protect\hfill%
    \underline{Page}}}}
\renewcommand\tableofcontents { \chapter*{\contentsname}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
\@starttoc{toc}}
\renewcommand\listoffigures { \chapter*{\listfigurename}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\@starttoc{lof}}
\renewcommand\listoftables { \chapter*{\listtablename}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\@starttoc{lot}}


\tableofcontents
\ifthenelse{\boolean{hastables}}{\listoftables}{}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{hasfigures}}{\listoffigures}{}
\@ifdefined{@prefacefile}{\makepreface}
\@ifdefined{@abbreviationsfile}{\makeabbreviations}
\newpage
\pagenumbering {arabic}
\setcounter {page}{1}}
```

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a \begin{document} before \listofequations?

Comment: Please turn this fragment of code into a working/compilable example

Comment: I'm using \documentclass[final]{york-thesis} document class @GonzaloMedina

Comment: This example isn't compilable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The described issue isn't seen in this example. I've added `\usepackage{tocbibind}` for including of `ToC` etc. into `ToC` and added the `LoE` to the `ToC` as well.

However, the manual usage of `\myequation` is error-prone and isn't recommended!

```
\documentclass[final]{york-thesis}

\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}

\xpretocmd{\listofmyequations}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listequationsname}}{}{}

\tableofcontents

%\makefrontmatter % can't use this command due to erros


\clearpage
\listofmyequations

\chapter{First chapter}

\section{First section}

\begin{equation}
E=mc^2 
\end{equation}
\myequations{Some equation}

%\input{Chapter1}
%\input{Chapter2}
%\input{Chapter3}
%\input{Chapter4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solved issues 2 and 3, but not the first issue where the Table of Content, List of Tables and List of Figures are not starting at the beginning of pages.

Comment: @Faa: If I change to `book.cls` I get effectively the same output for the Table of Contents -- it starts at about 3.5in from the top. Whatever you've done -- it's not in your example shown to us

Comment: I added `\clearpage` befor `\tableofcontents`, `\ifthenelse{\boolean{hastables}}{\listoftables}{}` and `\ifthenelse{\boolean{hasfigures}}{\listoffigures}{}` and they started at the beginning of pages. Thank you