# add a space in \addcontentsline command for list of equations

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

This is a follow-up question to [Creating List of Equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/270611/5764).

I think the spacing issue happened when the equation number is greater than 9 (shown in the image). I tried to add a space with `\vspace` and `\quad` in `\addcontentsline` but it didn't work any one have a clue?

[image]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle isn't that the page number? I would guess setting `\cftXnumwidth` for a suitable value of X

Comment: @DavidCarlisle illegal units of measure and some other errors

Comment: Well, if the relevant answer (it's mine in the linked question) was useful, use `\addtolength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{10pt}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127643/fix-formatting-errors-of-page-number-99-in-table-of-contents doesnt fix it

Comment: @ChristianHupfer i dont see where or how to use addtolength illegal units of measure again indeed your answer in the relatde link is useful maybe you would update it to take >9 number into consideration, DavidCarlisle it's ok :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: A typical misuse of the golden badge hammer :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the relevant question/answer given in the link (it's mine, actually ;-)) still holds, then use `\addtolength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{15pt}` (or choose another appropiate value)

`\newlistof{foo}{...}{}` will define all the relevant length registers and commands that resemble `\cftchapnumwidth` etc.

```
\documentclass[final]{book}

\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\addtolength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{15pt}
\xpretocmd{\listofmyequations}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listequationsname}}{}{}

\tableofcontents

%\makefrontmatter % can't use this command due to errors


\clearpage
\listofmyequations

\chapter{First chapter}

\section{First section}

\begin{equation}
E=mc^2 
\end{equation}
\myequations{Some equation}



\end{document}
```