# Use titletoc to create a new list of equation

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, titletoc

From this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270611/creating-list-of-equations) it is possible to create a list of equation (or other object). But the solution suggested in the answer is using `tocloft`. Therefore, I would like to know if it's possible to do this kind of things using the `titletoc` package ?

## EDIT

I tried with this MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

%\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}
    
    \startcontents[equ]
    \newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
    \newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par
    }
    
    \tableofcontents
    \printcontents[equ]{}{1}{List of equation}
    
    \chapter{First chapter}
    
    \section{First section}
    
    \begin{equation}
        C=2\pi R
    \end{equation}
    
    \begin{equation}
        E=mc^2 
    \end{equation}
    %\caption{caption of equation}
    \myequations{Some equation}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the result is not very attractive. From what I understand, the table of contents and the list of equations are mixed because of my command `\myequation`, plus the numbers are wrong. But how separate these two lists ?

Comment: This should be possible with `\startcontents` and `\stopcontents` etc. but you still have to provide the manual `\addcontentsline` entries to the relevant `ToC` file, i.e. a `.lie` (list of equations)

Comment: Your suggestion seems interesting but I don't know how to connect `\startcontents` with the relevant entry. Could you give me an example ?