# Change pagenumbering into Roman in List of Equation created with tocloft package

Tags: tocloft, roman

How can I change the page numbering into Roman numerals?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\pagenumbering{roman}

%%% LIST OF EQUATIONS %%%
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof[section]{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsindent}{1.5em}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.3em}
\renewcommand{\cftequtitlefont}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}


\newpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\listofmyequations

\newpage
\section{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{Text/2)}
\section{Section 1}
\input{Text/3)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\pagenumbering{Roman}` did not changed the page numbering.

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:Eq1}
\begin{split}
&U_{it} - U_{i,t-L} = \alpha + \sum_{j=1}^{J} \beta_{j}(E_{i,t-jL}-E_{i,t-(j+1)L}) \\ 
&+\sum_{j=1}^{J} \gamma_{j}(U_{i,t-jL}-U_{i,t-(j+1)L}) +\sum_{t=1}^{T} \delta_{t}D_{t} + \epsilon_{1it} 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\myequations{Equation number \ref{eq:Eq1}}
```

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem. What is the class you are using? How do you specify an equation?. What do you mean by the "page numbering"; the page number of the List of Equations or the page number of the equation entry? Your graphic showed no page number for the List of Equations.

Comment: I mean the page number of the equation entry (31) into XXXI, for example. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is your code based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270611 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173102? If yes, please reference that accordingly. That makes it easier for others to help.

Comment: I am confused. The equation is placed on a page with an Arabic page number but do you want that it appears in the ToE as a roman page number?

Answer (score 0):

- Here is a minimal code example that shows something related to your question.
- But I do not understand your question: The equation is placed on a page with an Arabic page number but do you want that it appears in the ToE as a roman page number?

---

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173102
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.5em}% Width of equation number in List of Equations

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman} 
\listofmyequations
\clearpage
%\pagenumbering{arabic} 

\section{Section}

\begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
\label{eq:NiceEquation}
\myequations{Nice equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]